# Check box not activating on Chrome [Version 101.0.4951.41 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

Edit: It seems as if my checkboxes are not working at all. When a regular checkbox was added to my HTML, it also did not respond to click events.

I am currently working on a dat.gui menu for my THREE.JS project.

Here is my project: https://codesandbox.io/s/ray-test-km2wru?file=/src/World.js:5581-5741

You will see that clicking the checkbox should change the equation for the plane as seen on lines 144. I am noticing that checkbox, when clicked, doesn't uncheck on chrome. However, when tested in firefox, the checkbox will unclick and switch the value of planeSpecs.waveXY to false.

```
  _createPlane() {
    // Dat.GUI controllers
    let planeSpecs = {
      scaler: 1,
      speed: 1,
      waveXY: true
    };
    let planeMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 0x6d6e6d,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      wireframe: true
    });

    // Creates a single plane with wireframe
    let planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25, 25, 200, 200);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    const planeFolder = this._GUI.addFolder("Plane");
    // These scales work
    planeFolder.add(planeSpecs, "scaler", 1, 10);
    planeFolder.add(planeSpecs, "speed", 0.1, 25);


    // This checkbox code doesn't work:
    const waveXYController = this._GUI
      .add(planeSpecs, "waveXY")
      .listen()
      .onChange((newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue);
      });
    planeFolder.open();


    plane.position.y -= 3;
    plane.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);

    // Animation for the plane
    plane.tick = (delta, elapsedTime) => {
      const { position } = planeGeo.attributes;
      for (let i = 0; i < position.count; i++) {
        let x = position.getX(i);
        let y = position.getY(i);
        let z = position.getZ(i);

        // Change the equation based on checkbox boolean
        z = planeSpecs.waveXY
          ? Math.sin(
              Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)) +
                elapsedTime * planeSpecs.speed
            ) * planeSpecs.scaler
          : Math.sin(x + elapsedTime * planeSpecs.speed) * planeSpecs.scaler;
        position.setXYZ(i, x, y, z);
      }
      position.needsUpdate = true;
    };
    return plane;
  }
```

From what I have researched, they way I added the dat.gui seems to be correct: https://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2015/07/datgui-easy-way-to-allow-users-to.html

I did make a forum post on the Three.JS forums, but after figuring out this is a browser issue I made a post here instead: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/dat-gui-checkbox-not-working-on-chrome/37642/2

Comment: Does a regular html `<input type="checkbox">` work? It might be a browser bug if that’s the only one it doesn’t work on.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work so it may be a browser bug. When I added a HTML checkbox to my html, it would allow me to use it. How and where would I go about finding out how to fix this?

Comment: Update: the issue was that the orbital controls plugin for three js is interfering with the event listeners for the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the THREE.JS library plugin Orbit Controls was adding event listeners to the body element, resulting in the dat.gui not being able to receive mouse inputs.

To avoid this, the second parameter for [OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) should be a dom element.
eg. `new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`
Though, in the latest versions of three.js this second paramater is enforced.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).